# Gio copy all files from shared folder

Tags: samba, copy

I want to copy all files from shared windows folder to my local folder In Ubuntu. I am using gio and following row:

```
gio copy smb://computerName/FoldName/* ~/localFolder/
```

but the result is gio: smb://...../*: Invalid argument

How to copy all files from share folder in local folder with GIO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing I can suggest is to use a standard copy ( cp ) command to transfer the files.

When you did your original mount:

```
gio mount smb://computerName/FoldName
```

It created a mount point at:

```
/run/user/$UID/gvfs/smb-share:server=computerName,share=FolderName
```

You can use cp to copy the contents to your local folder:

```
cp -r /run/user/$UID/gvfs/smb-share:server=computerName,share=FolderName/* ~/localFolder/
```